# Android Conductor - how to insert one controller to another as view?

Tags: conductor

I have some controller classes with own implementations. Is it possible to insert one to another as view in viewgroup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, this is what child controllers are. From the readme:

`getChildRouter can be called on a Controller in order to get a nested Router into which child Controllers can be pushed. This enables creating advanced layouts, such as Master/Detail.`